# 3B+ fails to boot Ubuntu mate

Tags: pi-3b+, ubuntu

I have the problem that the bootloader and kernel are too old in the mate image to run the on the new hardware.

Raspian works fine with a noobs install.

I tried the advice in the thread here

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=208538

Taking the kernel7.img and 3+.dtb file it still doesn't work, the final part of advice is... To copy across

/lib/modules/*-v7+

But I can't find that folder anywhere and using a windows PC none of the img files on the raspian sd mount windows just says they are corrupt.

Can someone please help get mate booting on a 3B+?

TIA

Comment: See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/81718/ubuntu-16-04-server-boot-to-rainbow-screen-on-pi-3-model-b/81719#81719

Comment: But it doesn't even boot, all the solutions i've found involve using an older Pi and updating it and swapping the SD card, i only have a windows PC and the 3b+

Comment: If you only have Windows it is next to impossible. Using a Linux OS it can (probably) be done with difficulty.  Otherwise you need to wait for an Ubuntu MATE update (which may or may not happen). There may be a 18.04 install, although this is not guaranteed.

Comment: Yeah I'm just making an ubuntu desktop boot usb - I couldn't find an 18.04 install yet for a Pi... waiting might be the only option.

Do you know which img file the /lib/modules/ is in?

Comment: I've copied over some of the files, the bootcode.bin, the kernel7.img, the kernel and its started to boot but ends with

[url=https://ibb.co/cm7UKn][img]https://preview.ibb.co/bFGdC7/image1.jpg[/img][/url]

end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(179,7)

Comment: It should boot without the modules -- but you will have restricted functionality, so you do need to copy them in.  Your Windows computer cannot read the root filesystem by default; you need either a linux VM or some add-on software (to read `ext4`).  The problem with "unable to mount root fs" is it is looking for partition 7.  I doubt Ubuntu uses that many.  Copy paste your `cmdline.txt` (from the boot partition) into the question.

Comment: Yeah I updated the cmdline.txt with partition 2 and got it booting to the splash screen, then it black screens there is maybe 40sec of intense SD card activity then that LED goes dormant and nothing happens.  

I tried plugging in an analog tft to see if anything was displayed there to no avail :(

Answer (score 0):

To get it working you copy the following to the boot partition from an up to date raspian image...

bootcode.bin, fixup.dat, start.elf, bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb , kernel.img, kernel7.img

Then copy from the root partition

/lib/modules folder: 4.9.80-v7+ and 4.9.80+

Then it boots, no wifi though.

Comment: To fix WiFi set the WiFi country with `sudo raspi-config`

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.